# Show that $ \mathbb{P}(A)=0 $ for each $ A \in \mathcal{F} $ with $ \sum \limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}\left(A_{k} \cap A\right)<\infty $.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $\{A_{n}\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subset \mathcal{F} $

such that $ \sum \limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}\left(A_{k}\right)=\infty $ holds.

Further, suppose that $ A_{n} $ is a sequence of stochastically independent events.

Show that $ \mathbb{P}(A)=0 $ for each $ A \in \mathcal{F} $ with $ \sum \limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}\left(A_{k} \cap A\right)<\infty $.

Note: First show that for any $ C \in \mathcal{F} $ with $ \mathbb{P}(C)=1 $, the equation $ \mathbb{P}(B \cap C)=\mathbb{P}(B) $ holds for all $ B \in \mathcal{F} $. Then use Borel-Cantelli's lemma twice.

Attempt:

1. Step of the hint:

If $P(C)=1$, let $C^\complement$ denotes the complement of $C$. First note that
$$
P(C^\complement) = 1-P(C) = 0
$$
and by monotonicity we see that $P(C^\complement \cap B) = 0$. Therefore,
\begin{align*}
P(C\cap B) = P(C\cap B) + P(C^\complement \cap B)
&=P([C\cap B]\cup [C^\complement \cap B])\\
&=P([C\cup C^\complement]\cap B)\\ 
&= P(B)\\
&=P(B)\cdot P(C)
\end{align*}
where the last line holds since $P(C)=1$. So once again we have $P(C\cap B) = P(C)\cdot P(B)$ which shows that $C$ and $B$ are independent.

But how can I use Borel-Cantelli's lemma on this? Any suggestions?

Comment: What was your attempt ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Borel-Cantelli gives since the $A_n$'s are independent that $\mathbb{P}(\limsup A_n)=1$ and that $\mathbb{P}(\limsup(A_n\cap A))=0$.
Using what you have shown, the result follows if $\limsup(A_n\cap A)=(\limsup A_n)\cap A$, but this follows fairly easily from the definition of the $\limsup$ of sets.